# Using Jekyll docker inside Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jekyll

I'm trying to build a jekyll website via my Jenkins server (which runs inside a container) and I have a stage in my `Jenkinsfile` that looks like this:

```
stage('Building Website') {

      agent {

        docker {
            image 'jekyll/jekyll:builder'
        }

      }

      steps {
        sh 'jekyll --version'
      }
}
```

The very first time I run my job it pulls the jekyll docker image and runs fine (although it does fetch a bunch of gems before running jekyll which doesn't happen when I run the docker manually outside jenkins) but then the next jobs fail giving this error:

```
jekyll --version
/usr/jekyll/bin/jekyll: exec: line 15: /usr/local/bundle/bin/jekyll: not found
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in the jenkins log file, jenkins runs docker with the `-u 1000:1000` argument, since this user does not exits in the `jekyll/jekyll` image, the command fails with the error `.../bin/jekyll: not found`

Here is a sample `Jenkinsfile`:

```
pipeline {
    agent
    {
        docker
        {
            image 'jekyll/jekyll:3.8'
            args '''
                -u root:root
                -v "${WORKSPACE}:/srv/jekyll"
            '''
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                    cd /srv/jekyll
                    jekyll --version
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answer, note the containerized Jenkins doesn't not contain the docker binary, so docker commands will still fail.

A few solutions

1. Make a dockerfile that inherits from the jenkins image and installs docker as well, creating a new image.
2. Manually install docker inside of the container. This will work until you pull a new image, and you'll have to do it over again.

Open an interactive terminal into the jenkins container

`docker container exec -it -u root <container id> bash`

Then install docker

`curl https://get.docker.com/ > dockerinstall && chmod 777 dockerinstall && ./dockerinstall`

Exit the container and set perms on docker.sock

`sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock`

Finished!